# Are Loops Possible in Detox testing

Tags: detox

Is it possible to loop through items in Detox? For example if you have many testid’s of the same type that simply increment by 1 in name, can it be looped in way that wouldn’t require the statements to be fully typed out each time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. Here you can see the code of a test that:

1. loads first screen
2. loops through a small list of items

   1. taps nth item
   2. navigates to second screen
   3. grabs a screenshot

Hope it helps

```
const { takeScreenshot } = require ('./helpers')

describe('Example', () => {
  let artistList, artistListItem
  let tagsList

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative();
  })
  afterEach(async () => {
    takeScreenshot() //https://medium.com/async-la/e2e-testing-react-native-with-detox-screenshots-595146073863
  })

  var fnTest=(i)=>{
    it('should navigate to '+i+'nth artist', async () => {
      await expect(element(by.id('artistList'))).toBeVisible()
      await element(by.id('artistListItem'+i)).tap()
    })
  }

  for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
    fnTest(i)
  }
})
```

[image: Test results]